# how to make a subset of cells expressing certain gene in seurat R

Tags: r, subset, sequence, seurat

I want to create a subset of a cell expressing certain genes only. Here is my coding but it always shows

> 'No named arguments passed'

I have no idea how to correct that.

```
Dbh.pos <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh > 0, slot = "data"))
Dbh.neg <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh = 0, slot = "data"))
```

Comment: Try ```expression = Dbh == 0``` for the second line of code. Arguments use ```=``` while operators use ```==```, normally.

Comment: I try this and show another error:     Dbh.pos <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh == >0, slot = "data"))
Error: unexpected '>' in "Dbh.pos <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh == >"

Comment: Looks like you altered Dbh.pos?  I meant for you to try your original code for Dbh.pos, but alter Dbh.neg to```Dbh.neg <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh == 0, slot = "data"))```

Comment: Still show the same problem:        Dbh.pos <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh >0, slot = "data"))
Error in CheckDots(...) : No named arguments passed
Dbh.neg <- Idents(my.data, WhichCells(my.data, expression = Dbh == 0, slot = "data"))
Error in CheckDots(...) : No named arguments passed

Comment: Hmmm...Easier to troubleshoot if you would post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that describes what's in your my.data object.

Comment: What do you mean about minimal reproducible example? "my.data" is a seurat object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207702/discussion-between-elaine-and-xilliam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset from the counts matrix, below I use pbmc_small dataset from the package, and I get cells that are CD14+ and CD14-:

```
library(Seurat)
CD14_expression = GetAssayData(object = pbmc_small, 
assay = "RNA", slot = "data")["CD14",]
```

This vector contains the counts for CD14 and also the names of the cells:

```
head(CD14_expression,30)
ATGCCAGAACGACT CATGGCCTGTGCAT GAACCTGATGAACC TGACTGGATTCTCA AGTCAGACTGCACA 
      0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000 
TCTGATACACGTGT TGGTATCTAAACAG GCAGCTCTGTTTCT GATATAACACGCAT AATGTTGACAGTCA 
      0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000 
AGGTCATGAGTGTC AGAGATGATCTCGC GGGTAACTCTAGTG CATGAGACACGGGA TACGCCACTCCGAA 
      0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000 
CTAAACCTGTGCAT GTAAGCACTCATTC TTGGTACTGAATCC CATCATACGGAGCA TACATCACGCTAAC 
      0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000 
TTACCATGAATCGC ATAGGAGAAACAGA GCGCACGACTTTAC ACTCGCACGAAAGT ATTACCTGCCTTAT 
      3.542611       3.917231       4.552789       5.159975       3.117873 
CCCAACTGCAATCG AAATTCGAATCACG CCATCCGATTCGCC TCCACTCTGAGCTT CATCAGGATGCACA 
      0.000000       3.452557       3.820847       4.432036       0.000000
```

Getting the ids can be done using `which` :

```
    pos_ids = names(which(CD14_expression>0))
    neg_ids = names(which(CD14_expression==0))
```

Subsetting of the data can be done with:

```
    pos_cells = subset(pbmc_small,cells=pos_ids)
    neg_cells = subset(pbmc_small,cells=neg_ids)
```

A bit dumb, but I guess this is one way to check whether it works:

```
    FeaturePlot(pos_cells,"CD14")
    FeaturePlot(neg_cells,"CD14")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to actually add the information directly on the meta.data.
Here, the **GEX = pbmc_small**, for exemple.
Using the same logic as @StupidWolf, I am getting the gene expression, then make a dataframe with two columns, and this information is directly added on the Seurat object.

```
GENE="Cd8a"
EXPR = GetAssayData(object=GEX,assay="RNA",slot="data")[GENE,]
EXPR_df=data.frame( positive= EXPR > 0, negative = EXPR == 0)
names(GEX)<-paste0( c("positive_","negative_"),GENE)
GEX <- AddMetaData(GEX,metadata=EXPR_df)
```

This approach allows then to subset nicely, with more flexibility.

```
GEX_subset <- subset(GEX, annot == "T cell" & negative_Cd8a)
```